# would rather something

Tags: would-rather

I have a question about the usage of "would rather". We usually say: "I would rather do somthing" and it's correct. But can we say: "I would rather something"?

For example, in these situations item b is correct, but what about item a?

- We can have tea or coffee.
  a: I'd rather coffee.
  b: I'd rather **have** coffee.
- We can see a comedy or a documentary.
  a: I would rather the comedy.
  b: I would rather **see** the comedy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rather is usually followed by a verb. I'd rather have coffee [instead of tea.]
That said, in context, you could possibly say: I'd rather coffee. In a conversation, where the context has already been set. But, strictly speaking, one generally would not.

Comment: Yes. Because _I'd rather_ = _I would rather_, and "would" is a modal which needs a following verb. (This sort of logical argument doesn't always work with real languages, but often it does).